# Decompose arctangent of a fraction

Tags: trigonometry

I am familiar with standard goniometric identities, but not so much with inverse functions.

Given a function of the form $\arctan(X/Y)$, is it possible to separate the X variable from Y? I want to algebraically eliminate X in an equation of the form $A \arctan(X/Y1)$ = $B\arctan(X/Y2)$.

Comment: It's doable if it's of the form $\arctan \frac{X-Y}{1+XY}$ or $\arctan \frac{X+Y}{1-XY}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nikunj wrote,
$\arctan(u)+\arctan(v)
=\arctan(\frac{u+v}{1-uv})
$.

Therefore,
if
$X
=u+v$
and
$Y
=1-uv
$,
$v = X-u$
so
$Y
=1-u(X-u)
=u^2-uX+1
$
or
$u^2-uX+1-Y
=0
$
so
$u
=\frac{X\pm\sqrt{X^2+4(Y-1)}}{2}
$
and
$v
=X-u
=\frac{-X\mp\sqrt{X^2+4(Y-1)}}{2}
$.

You can then do

$\begin{array}\\
\arctan(\frac{X}{Y})
&=\arctan(\frac{u+v}{1-uv})\\
&=\arctan(u)+\arctan(v)\\
&=\arctan\left(\frac{X\pm\sqrt{X^2+4(Y-1)}}{2}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{-X\mp\sqrt{X^2+4(Y-1)}}{2}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

This may or may not be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't make my life easier :). For reference I was trying to work out the object-image distance formula based on Snell's Law. But without the assumption of small incident angles.